# Rectangles uneven in CV2 grid

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a grid on a (very) large image. I am using cv2 and Python 3 for reference. See the following code:

```
output_image = np.zeros((23000, 23000), dtype=np.int)
output_image = np.uint8(np.stack((output_image, output_image, output_image), 2)*255)
...
import cv2

def visualise_tiles(image, num_tiles):
    X = image[:,0]
    Y = image[:,1]

    x_range = int(max(X) - min(X))
    y_range = int(max(Y) - min(Y))
    x_step = int((max(X) - min(X)) // num_tiles)
    y_step = int((max(Y) - min(Y)) // num_tiles)

    for i in tqdm(range(num_tiles)):
        for j in range(num_tiles):
            x_left, y_left = x_step * i, y_step * (j + 1)
            x_right, y_right = x_step * (i + 1), y_step * j
            cv2.rectangle(output_image, (x_left, y_left), (x_right, y_right), (255, 255, 0), 100)
```

When given a specific image, the x_range is 9786 and y_range is 21674. The x_step thus evaluates to 489, and the y_step to 1083. This is fine, and we expect the resultant rectangles to be non-square, which they are. All good.

My problem is that there is some weird 'stretching' that goes on in the output and the rectangles are uneven, whereas I want a perfect grid. See in particular the attached image at 15000 on the y-axis and 5000 on the x-axis:

[image: Visual results when plotted with plt.imshow()]

I am not sure why this is - can anyone explain?

Comment: You show an image with 10000 pixels in an axes which comprises of 220 pixels. Chances you see a single pixels are hence 220/10000 = 2%. I think you are extraordinary lucky to actually see more then every 50th line.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So it's just the scale? Is there any way of rectifying this?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last argument of `rectangle`, and I also misinterpreted the text. So you have 23000 points in the array and want to show a yellow region of 100 points on 220 pixels, so chances are 95% to see the line, which is more of what you actually observe. Solutions: make the figure larger, make a line wider (e.g 200 instead of 100), draw the grid with matplotlib instead of changing the pixels in the image.